# What articles or books are currently considered canonical in the discussion of a priori knowledge and justification?

Tags: logic, knowledge

Quine's "Two Dogmas", I think, would be one. Perhaps also Putnam's "Is Logic Empirical". If you wanted to doubt the existence of a priori knowledge or justification on the basis of the apparently impossible reference it makes to a time prior to experience or the apparent fact that all our thinking occurs in language which we only have through experience, what books and articles might help, which ones would require responses?

Comment: I gave some references in What are the more interesting examples of synthetic a priori statements? http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37726/what-are-the-more-interesting-examples-of-synthetic-a-priori-statements/37733#37733 see also Is Logic Empirical http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37768/is-logic-empirical/37787#37787 The consequences of doubts you have became the mainstream in modern philosophy, few believe in absolute eternal knowledge. The notion of a priori was changed accordingly, they no longer mean what Kant meant, and in particular they are fallible.